# django - query filter on manytomany is empty

Tags: django, django-queryset

In Django is there a way to filter on a manytomany field being empty or null.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('set name'), max_length=200)
    manytomany = models.ManyToManyField('AnotherModel', blank=True, null=True)

print TestModel.objects.filter(manytomany__is_null=True)
```

Answer (score 203, accepted):

```
print TestModel.objects.filter(manytomany=None)
```

Comment: And the inverse is possible with `TestModel.objects.exclude(manytomany=None)`

Comment: Is there a way to query unrelated/unattached objects in the 'AnotherModel'?  Trying to clean up a many to many model.

Comment: Using `AnotherModel.objects.filter(testmodel_set=None)` worked for me. If you're using a [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), you should of course use that instead.

Answer (score 15):

Adding to @Bernhard answer, other possible solution can be achieved using the `Q()` object.

```
from django.db.models import Q

filters = Q(manytomany=None)

TestModel.objects.filter(filters)
```

**Negation:**

```
filters = ~Q(manytomany=None)

TestModel.objects.filter(filters)
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the topic has already an answer this could be of help. Try with lookups:

```
empty = TestModel.objects.filter(manytomany__isnull = True)
#........If you want to get their counter part
not_empty = TestModel.objects.filter(manytomany__isnull = False)
```

Basically, you get two query sets: one where your manytomany fields are empty, and the other with objects that have data in the manytomanyfield.

Hope this could be of some help!

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question but I needed it and the provided answers didn't work for me, but I did fix it and got the proper filtering (on Django  2.2) this is how:

```
testModel.objects.filter(testmodel__anothermodel=None)
```

as you can see using the model name all lower case then two underscores then the many to many model name that did it for me