# Pythonically filter Django queryset based on lack of reverse relationships

Tags: django

Suppose I have two Django models, let's say Product and Manufacturer, and wish to find Manufacturers who have no Products.

```
class Product(Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
class Manufacturer(Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

I want to generate a set of all Manufacturer objects that are *not referred to by any Product objects*. I can think of many ways to get this set, but none of them seem clean or **Pythonic**

1. Given the queryset of all Products, generate a set of all Manufacturers that have products. Then take the set difference of all manufacturers with the manufacturers_with_products as described here: [How to get the difference of two querysets in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945912/how-to-get-the-difference-of-two-querysets-in-django).
2. Filter the Manufacturer objects based on the lack of a reverse relationship with any Products. Django makes it easy to filter based on properties of reverse relationships, but I cannot find a clean way to filter based on the *existence* of this reverse relationship.

eg, I can trivially filter Manufacturers that have at least one Product that satisfies a condition:

```
models.Manufacturer.objects.filter(product__name=x)
```

I'd like to be able to filter something more like

```
models.Manufacturer.objects.exclude(product__exists)
```

I could probably exclude/filter Manufacturers on some axiom/tautology of Products, but that also doesn't seem very Pythonic.

Comment: For `ManyToManyField`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4184558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using an [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/) and a filter:

```
from django.db.models import Count
idle = Manufacturers.objects.annotate(num_products=Count('product')).filter(num_products=0)
```

`idle` will the contain a list of Manufacturers who have no products, but keep in mind they will also have a property `num_products`, which due to the query will be 0.