# Django: check if ManyToManyField is empty from a Field object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This seems super simple but surprisingly could not find any clue on SO or Django docs yet.

I want to check if a particular ManyToManyField is empty but cant figure out a way to do it yet. Here's my exact usecase, if it helps:

```
for field in school._meta.get_fields(): # school is the Model object 
    if (field.get_internal_type() == 'ManyToManyField'):
        #if (find somehow if this m2m field is empty)
            #do something if empty
    else:
        if (field.value_to_string(self) and field.value_to_string(self)!='None'):
            #do something when other fields are blank or null
```

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184558/django-query-filter-on-manytomany-is-empty) post which looks similar but is about filtering all ManyToManyFields that are empty in a Model object, so doesn't help the case above.

`all()` or `count()` or `empty()` or `exists()` don't seem to work on ManyToManyFields.

`if (field):` returns `True` (since its referring to the Manager)

Didn't find a relevant option in the [Field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-options) or [ManyToManyField reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getattr(school,field.name).exists()` worked for me. But all ears to know if there's a better approach

(i.e querying on model_object.field instead of field object)

Answer (score 1):

How about using `first()` instead? That should definitely run quicker than `all()` and may run quicker than `count()`.

IE:

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.m2mField.first():
        print('Object where m2mField contains stuff.')
    else:
        print('Object with nothing in m2mField.')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was overriding the `clean()` method for a model and had to perform validation if the m2m field was empty. `getattr()` returned an exception so I had to use `.count()`. This should also work for django-modelcluster's `ParentalManyToMany` fields.

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):  
    if self.m2m_field.count() == 0: 
            raise ValidationError("No children")
```

Comment: this way, will result in a server-error, because the object is saved yet, so it does not have an ID, and then we could not call self.m2m_field.* for an object which is not saved.